# Is 14.04 LTS sufficient for for dual CPUs

Tags: system-installation, dell

I am totally new to UBUNTU (and dual CPUs).  Do I just download the current iso (14.04 LTS 64-bit) from www.ubuntu.com/download/server, or do I need something else to support a server using dual cpus?

I have a Dell PowerEdge R720 server with dual Intel Xeon E5-2637v2 4c 3.5GHz CPUs; with hardware based RAID (PERC H710P); iDRAC7 Express...  We have placed it on the rack and upgraded the BIOS.

I am after the usual LAMP system.

Answer (score 0):

From the desktop distro, ubuntu supports multiple CPU without any further config.

Since you're new to Ubuntu and Ubuntu server, you might take a few minutes to [read this document](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf)